# How to save a QR code generated from the Electrum Wallet directly as a PNG or JPG file?

Tags: networking, image-processing, bitcoin, kwallet, xclip

How do I save and send the QR code:

[image: electrum]

as a `jpg` or `png`?

There are ways to use `gimp` and/or `xclip` but I would hope that I can just save the `QR` code directly to file.  Is this possible?

Notably, Windows has the handy windows-shift-s which will allow an easy clip-and-save.  I'd resort to that if it's not possible to directly save the above `QR` code.

Answer (score 2):

Use Ubuntu's screenshot taking features. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen</kbd>, then select QR-code area at the screen using mouse. Selected area will be saved as a PNG image file in `~/Pictures` folder.

Comment: Is it possible to save the QR code directly from Electrum?

Comment: Sorry but I don't use Electrum application so I can't advice you something useful.

Comment: Even if it were possible, I hardly see how it could be easier than @Serg's method.